# Widow Tetra fish dying

Tags: aquarium, fish, tetra

My widow tetra fishes are dying one by one.They seem to float around with lack of control and seems gasping for air.I have quarantined this fish and added some common salt to help it breathe.

It is now floating in the surface and opening and closing its mouth repeatedly.

Is this some kind of infection that spreads.Please advise
[image]

Comment: Please add your latest reading of water test, I am sure this will hold valuable information for the fish-experts here :)

Comment: can you please post the readings of your PH-AMMONIA-NITRITE and information about if the tank is properly cycled,cycling a tank is the most important thing you do for the survival of your fish and you can read about it here https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm you need to use aquarium salt and not common salt in your tank(aquarium salt is often a mix of several salts in addition to sodium chloride)use a consentration of 0,3% aquarium salt to help against nitrite poisoning.